# How to properly use $_ inside a tcsh script sourced from another tcsh script?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I try to retrieve the result from `$_` inside a tcsh script itself sourced by another tcsh script (I'll refer to them respectively as the inner and outer script). But `$_` is not set with the value I expect (being the last command executed).

outer code:

```csh
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set lastCmd0 = ($_)
echo "${lastCmd0}"
echo "$0"
source inner
echo "enOuter"
```

inner code:

```csh
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set lastCmd1 = ($_)
echo "${lastCmd1}"
echo "$0"
echo "endInner"
```

Here are the output when calling `source outer`:

```
source outer 
tcsh
source outer 
tcsh
endInner
enOuter
```

**Q 1** Why is there two `source outer`, the second one shoudn't be `source inner`?

Here are the output when calling `./outer`:

```
./outer

./outer
endInner
enOuter
```

**Q 2** Why `$_` isn't set when sourcing inner ?

It seems that `$_` is never set again when executing a script, I don't know if it is a normal or not. Anyway if it is not possible to use `$_`, is there an alternative secure way to get the last command executed inside a script ?

Comment: Why would you even need `$_` from inside a script? This seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166789) to me. I think you're better off describing what exactly you're trying to do, rather than use an "abstract" example like this.

Comment: As to the answer "why does tcsh behave like this?" That's because it's crappy code dating back to the 1970s when Bill Joy write the first `csh` as a student and later admitted that he "didn't really know what he was doing". There are many quirks in (t)csh scripting, and is typically best avoided altogether if possible.

Comment: I agree with you, but some other scripts in the project are in tcsh (the project is old) and -- for now -- it's easier to not rewrite them all. But I definitely will have to rewrite them one day.

Answer (score 1):

`tcsh` can update the items in `argv()` if you provide parameters to the `source` command, but does not alter `$0` or `$_`.

You can see what is going on by changing the messages to show which variable is printed, and which script does it. First "outer":

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set lastCmd0 = ($_)
echo 'O:$lastCmd0'"=${lastCmd0}"
echo 'O:$0'"=$0"
source inner
echo 'O:endOuter'
```

and then "inner"

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set lastCmd1 = ($_)
echo 'I:$lastCmd1='"${lastCmd1}"
echo 'I:$0'"=$0"
echo 'I:endInner'
```

Output:

```
> tcsh -f
> source ./outer
O:$lastCmd0=source ./outer 
O:$0=tcsh
I:$lastCmd1=source ./outer 
I:$0=tcsh
I:endInner
O:endOuter
```

and

```
> source ./outer first second
#argv: 2
O:$lastCmd0=source ./outer first second 
O:$0=tcsh
I:$lastCmd1=source ./outer first second 
I:$0=tcsh
I:endInner
O:endOuter
```