# override value of $_ in linux csh script

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, csh

I would like to override value of $_ in linux csh script.

I run this script in xterm using cmdline:

```
chmod +x test.csh
test.csh
```

---

test.csh content:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
....
source sourceme.rc
....
```

---

sourceme.rc content:

```
...  
set cmd = "import sys; import os; print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[2]),'checkenv.py'))"
set checkenv = `python -c "$cmd" $_`
...
```

---

This $_ value in sourceme.rc should have the value of "**source sourceme.rc**" if "**source sourceme.rc**" is executed in xterm directly.

However the **source sourceme.rc** is ran using a csh script instead of directly source it using xterm, so the $_ value is blank.

I saw [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258402/how-to-properly-use-inside-a-tcsh-script-sourced-from-another-tcsh-script) that $_ is not altered, but is there a way to override the value of $_ inside test.csh? e.g.

> set _ = somevalue

Given that we do not want to edit the content of sourceme.rc

Thanks

Comment: Notice that `$_` is not special in the real `csh` (where you could just do a simple `set _ = value`), but only in `tcsh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that *nicely*.

In `tcsh`, `$_` always fetches the content of the input buffer (empty in a non-interactive shell), and there's no way to override it.

This kludge may work (ymmv):

```
set lastline = 'source sourceme.csh'
sed 's/\$_\>/$lastline/g' sourceme.csh | source /dev/stdin
```

Unlike `bash`, `dash`, etc `tcsh` will run the right side of a pipeline in the current process if it's not an external command, so any commands or variables assignments in `sourceme.csh` will happen in the main shell.

Comment: Thanks! This works well without having to modify the sourceme.csh
Btw, what does the \> means in the s/.../g ?